# Received an ElementClickInterceptedException after running while loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following website: https://signal.nfx.com/investor-lists/top-gaming-esports-seed-investors
The HTML code for the "Load More Button" is

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs sn-light-greyblue-accent-button sn-center mt3 mb2 btn btn-default">LOAD MORE GAMING/ESPORTS SEED INVESTORS</button>
```

My code is:

```
My Code Is 

    import selenium
    
    from selenium import webdriver

    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #first letting in first keywork 'keys' must be 
    small and first letter in second keywork 'Keys' must be in capital
    
    import time
    
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

    import time

    import requests

    PATH ="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    url = 'https://signal.nfx.com/investor-lists/top-gaming-esports-seed-investors'
    driver.get(url)

    while True:
      time.sleep(1.5)
      try:
        loadmore1= 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/button')
        loadmore1.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

After I run the while loop I receive this error message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="button" class="btn-xs sn-orange-button h2 w-100 w-50-l btn btn-primary">...</button> is not clickable at point (1695, 16). Other element would receive the click: <a role="button" href="#">...</a>
```

How can I correct this? on the URL the last load more option only loads three cards, which I believe is causing the issue. I would like to load every investor card and then scrape each card for data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep clicking the loadmore button try waiting for the button to come up using webdriver since they poll the page for the element to be interactable. You can also just skip or say something during the errors. Timeout exception or Nosuchelement.

```
url = 'https://signal.nfx.com/investor-lists/top-gaming-esports-seed-investors'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window() 
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 2) 
while True:
    try:
        loadmore1=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='LOAD MORE ']")))
        loadmore1.click()
    except:
        break
```